# Match returned as array instead of variable

Tags: regex, perl

I am pulling a simple string from between two XML-like tags, but the match is being returned as an array instead of a variable. I am using the following code:

```
$finishState = $inFileLine =~ m(<State>(.*?)<\/State>)g;
```

And the value of `$inFileLine` is:

```
<recordNum>SW001</recordNum><state>Assigned</state><title>Fix Something</title>
```

When I run this code, a "1" is stored in `$finishState`. When I change `$finishState` to `@finishState` the value "Assigned" is stored properly.

I'm unsure why and how to fix this. I'm absolutely not able to use an XML parser.

While having the value I need in an array doesn't kill me I would like to find out why this is happening and modify my regexp to correctly populate the variable.  I also considered using grep, sed, awk, etc. but a match seems like a concise and clean way to do this.

Comment: Since you're new to Perl, I'll make a plug for the excellent built-in documentation. The match operator is documented in [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#m%2f_PATTERN_%2fmsixpodualngc) (I've linked to the online version for your convenience, but you should also be able to run `perldoc perlop` in a shell to view it).

Comment: Thank you Sir!  I will review this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It  is called context. Perl is context based language, the result given by operand is based on which context you are evaluating it.

There are two types of context in perl.

1. Scalar context.
2. List context.

Lists are collection of scalars.We use arrays and hashes to name them.

```
my $finishState = $inFileLine =~ m(<State>(.*?)<\/State>)g;
```

In this case you are evaluating the expression in scalar context which is giving you the boolean value whether it is matched or not i.e `1(matched)` in your case..

```
my @finishState = $inFileLine =~ m(<State>(.*?)<\/State>)g;
```

In this case you are evaluating the expression as array so it will give you all the matches in the array.

So, you know there is only one match and you want to store it into scalar use `parenthesis` to evaluate it in list context.

i.e

```
my ($finishState) = $inFileLine =~ m(<State>(.*?)<\/State>)g;
```

Now `$finishState` will contain your match.

If there is more than one match, then  `$finishState` will contain the first match. Check [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=738558) and [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=291543) node for more information on contexts.

Comment: Wow, thank you.  I'm going to read this page 10 times until it sinks in.  Thank you very much for the lesson and answer.

Comment: Another reference that's more specific to this context is [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129)

Comment: Thank you ikegami!  I will look at that now.

Answer (score 3):

```
$finishState = $inFileLine =~ m(<State>(.*?)<\/State>)g;
```

evaluates the regular expression in scalar context, and populates `$finishState` with a true (1) or false (`""`) value.

```
@finishState = $inFileLine =~ m(<State>(.*?)<\/State>)g;
```

or even

```
($finishState) = $inFileLine =~ m(<State>(.*?)<\/State>)g;
```

evaluate the regular expression in list context. The distinction between scalar context and list context is important in Perl, and one of the greatest sources of confusion to new Perl programmers. Many functions and operations behave differently in the two different contexts, and often the only way to be sure what an operation is supposed to do in a particular context is to [read the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Matching-in-list-context).

[In this case](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Matching-in-list-context), `@finishState` will be populated by a list of all strings matching the capture group in the regular expression (i.e., all strings of length 0 of more enclosed by `<State>` and `</State>` tags), which in your example is a list of one element with the value `Assigned`.

Comment: My goodness you guys have tons of knowledge.  Thank you for the lesson.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would refer to `$1` to see the content of the first matching parentheses:

```
$inFileLine = '<recordNum>SW001</recordNum><state>Assigned</state><title>Fix Something</title>';
$inFileLine =~ m(<State>(.*?)<\/State>)i;
$finishState = $1;
print $finishState;
```

outputs

> Assigned

[perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#More-matching) states that

> In list context, //g returns a list of matched groupings, or if there are no groupings, a list of matches to the whole regex.

But the usual way would be to check the return value of the regex to find out whether there is any match, and to refer to `$1`, `$2` etc. to see the matches.

Comment: This is going to come in handy!  In my case I know that my line will only contain one match.  Thank you very much!